# Idempotent automorphisms

Tags: automorphism-group, idempotents

Are there any interesting examples of idempotent automorphisms $f:X\to X$ besides the identity, where $X$ is a structured space of some sort (or even just a class)?

My intuition says no since it seems that any function on a class $X$ which permutes a finite number of elements can't be idempotent unless it's the identity, but I'm not sure with infinite examples. To see this, observe that $$f(x)=y\ \text{and}\ f(y)=z\implies f^2(x)=z,$$ so if $y\neq z$ then $f$ can't be idempotent, so $f$ would have to be trivial on part of $X$. Let $${\sf fix}(f)=\{x\in X:f(x)=x\}$$ denote the fixed points of $f$. If $f$ is idempotent then $f(X)\subseteq{\sf fix}(f)$ by the above argument, so it seems like (for anything besides the identity) we would need $f$ not to be injective so we can map all elements of $X\setminus{\sf fix}(f)$ onto one element $y\in {\sf fix}(f)$ and be good to go, but endomorphic examples are trivial to come up with (e.g. any constant function on a point).

Comment: @Gae.S. I'm not very familiar with group theory, is $S_n$ the symmetric group on $n$ elements?

Comment: In what sense is $f$ an automorphism and not just an endomorphism if $f$ cannot be cancelled from both sides of $f^2=f$?

Comment: @runway44 An automorphism is a bijective endomorphism, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: If it's bijective, then it has an inverse, and you can apply the inverse to both sides of $f^2=f$ to get $f={\rm id}$, making your question trivial.

Comment: @runway44 That seems valid to me, how does this reconcile with the symmetric group example given by Gae?

Comment: @AlecRhea My example was wrong. I was confusing "idempotency" with "involution".

Comment: @Gae.S. Ah, got it, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @runway44 If you'd like to post that as an answer to close the question I'll accept.

Comment: @runway44 If you're curious, this question came up when considering wether vertical composition in a $2$-category distributes over horizontal composition.  Working out the algebra gives that the target $1$-cell of the $2$-cells we want the distributive law to hold for must be idempotent, and this together with your answer gives that vertical composition never distributes over horizontal composition for $2$-cells on isos except for the identity iso. A trivial answer, yes, but still some interesting mathematics.